# array packetizer in JSON format in C

Tags: arrays, c, json

I am developing the JSON array packetizer in C to send response back to http server

example format in JSON array

```
"fat": [
       23,
       152689,
      "Segmentation Fault"
    ]
```

Code in C

```
 void arrFunc(char* buffer, const char* name, const int* value, int count)
 {
     if ((buffer == NULL) || (name == NULL))
     {
         return;
     }

    char numberChar[VALUE_FIELD_LENGTH];
    strncat(buffer, "\"", 1);
    strncat(buffer, name, strlen(name));
    strncat(buffer, "\":", 2);
    strncat(buffer, "[", 1);
    if (value != NULL)
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    -    {
             snprintf(numberChar, VALUE_FIELD_LENGTH, "%u", value[i]);
             strncat(buffer, numberChar, 1);
             if(i<count-1)
                 strncat(buffer, ",", 1);
            numberChar[i] = '\0';
          }
    }
    strncat(buffer, "]", 1);
   }
   /* main *//
  int arr[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
  char* msg;
  if (msg != NULL)
  {
    msg[0] = '\0';
    arrFunc(msg, "fat",(const int *) arr,3);
   }
Output : 
"fat": [
        1,
        2,
        3
       ]
```

I am able to achieve array packetizer of similar data types like integer but how to achive for
different data type     [23,152689,"Segmentation Fault"]

Comment: The posted code seems to be incomplete

Comment: `char* msg;  if (msg != NULL)` hmmm... not good... `msg` is uninitialized. No memory assigned.

Comment: `arrFunc(msg, "fat",(const int *) arr,3,  false);` doesn't match the function definition

Comment: Anyway... C doesn't support arrays with mixed types

Comment: how to achieve the same

Comment: You can't mix types in a C array. So if the json example is to be an array, it can't be used in C

Comment: @EthaneDas: It seems like you are writing your own JSON parser in C. It would be better if you go with some already written JSON parser libraries in C e.g. json-c, https://github.com/zserge/jsmn etc., they are not great as Python JSON libraries but does the job

Comment: @EthaneDas: See this example https://github.com/zserge/jsmn/blob/master/example/simple.c

Comment: yes , i am using jsmn parser libraries but it only used to parse JSON string and we cannot send or make response in JSON format packetizing using jsmn library . Correct if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to solve this problem, but one of them is tagged unions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// TODO: include an implementation of a map
struct map {};
// TODO: include a dynamic array that knows size of data it holds
struct array {};

enum DataType {
    JSON_MAP,
    JSON_ARRAY,
    JSON_NUMBER,
    JSON_STRING
};

union Data {
    float number;
    char* string;
    struct map map;
    struct array array;
};

struct Json {
    enum DataType kind;
    union Data data;
};

// TODO: turn this into json serializer
void print_json(struct Json data) {
    switch(data.kind) {
        case JSON_NUMBER:
            printf("%d\n", data.data.number);
            break;
        case JSON_STRING:
            puts(data.data.string);
            break;
        default:
            puts("TODO: print map and array");
    }
}

int main() {
    struct Json data1 = { .kind = JSON_NUMBER, .data.number = 12.34 };
    struct Json data2 = { .kind = JSON_STRING, .data.string = "Hello, Json!" };
    // invalid, but we never read it in this example
    struct Json data3 = { .kind = JSON_ARRAY }; 

    print_json(data1);
    print_json(data2);
    print_json(data3);
}
```

I don't think this requires further explanation but keep in mind that both the map and array should hold elements of type `struct Json` too, which is how you can build structures such as:

```
{ // JSON_MAP
  "example": [ // JSON_ARRAY
    1, // JSON_NUMBER
    "42", // JSON_STRING
    { "etc": { "1": 2, "a": [3, 2, 1] } } // JSON_MAP (again)
  ]
}
```

Comment: I tries to implement the above but I am getting error for below syntax                                 struct map {};
struct array {};

Comment: @EthaneDas those are placeholders and should be replaced with a real map and vector of your choice.

Comment: please atleast provide one example then i will tried to modify. Because i am new to JSON

Comment: @EthaneDas example of what exactly? A complete working solution? There's plenty of JSON libraries already.

Comment: there is no plenty of example in C .Thanks for the help

Comment: @EthaneDas I'd say over [52000 repositories](https://github.com/search?q=json+c) doing more or less exact same thing, is more than enough to find a C library and look at the source code, alongside with 50 lines of code I wrote that give an idea of how to do it in one specific way. You haven't explained what problem you have, so I can't help you.

Comment: I want to develop array packetizer in JSON format for different data types in C